# Spark/Scala - unix_timestamp returning the wrong date?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, epoch

I have a piece of Spark code that looks like this:

```
df //existing dataframe
  .withColumn("input_date", lit("20190105"))
  .withColumn("input_date_epoch", unix_timestamp(col("input_date"), "YYYYMMdd"))
```

Now, when I run a `df.describe` the data returned shows the `input_date_epoch` column having all values as `1546128000`, which when I run through an epoch converter comes out as 2018-12-30 00:00:00, rather than the expected value of 2019-01-05 00:00:00

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern is wrong, if you want a year with four digits, use `yyyy`:

```
spark.range(5)
  .withColumn("input_date", lit("20190105"))
  .withColumn("input_date_epoch", unix_timestamp(col("input_date"), "yyyyMMdd"))
```

`YYYYY` actually refers to weekyear, see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)